# Unable to redirect standard output using CreateProcess

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc

I'm maintaining an MFC program and I'm launching a simple Win32 console program (just a "Hello World" program, source below) with `CreateProcess` and I'm unable to redirect the standard output of that program to a file.

This is the launching code, don't bother about the `Fatal` function, it just
displays a message and aborts the program, this is only test code.

```
  HANDLE hfile = CreateFile("output.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  if (hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    Fatal("Fatal error: CreateFile");
  }

  static const char TestText[] = "Test\r\n";
  DWORD written;
  if (!WriteFile(hfile, "Test\r\n", sizeof(TestText) - 1, &written, NULL))
  {
    Fatal("Fatal error: CreateProcess");
  }

  STARTUPINFO startupinfo = {0};
  startupinfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
  startupinfo.lpTitle = "Some Title";
  startupinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  startupinfo.hStdOutput = hfile; 

  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

  if (!CreateProcess("S:\\Git\\TestRedirect\\TestConsole1\\Debug\\TestConsole1.exe", "cmdline", NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startupinfo, &processInfo))
  {
    Fatal("Fatal error: CreateProcess");
  }

  if (WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, 10000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    Fatal("Fatal error: WaitForSingleObject");
  }

  if (!CloseHandle(hfile))
  {
    Fatal("Fatal error: CloseHandle");
  }
```

It almost works as expected:

- it opens "output.txt"
- it writes "Test\r\n" into "output.txt"
- it launches TestConsole1.exe
- the console window of TestConsole1.exe does not display "Hello Word", which is expected because the standard output is supposed to be redirected into "output.txt"
- `WaitForSingleObject` waits for TestConsole1.exe to be completed
- `CloseHandle` closes "output.txt"

Now I expect "output.txt" to contain this:

> Test
>   Hello World!

but actually it's content is

> Test

---

Source code of TestConsole1.exe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    Sleep(2000);    // wait 2 seconds so I can see what happens
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `hfile` is not inheritable - you need use `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` in call `CreateFile`

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), 0, TRUE };
HANDLE hfile = CreateFile("output.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Comment: Feeling so stupid. It's even written clearly in the documentation. But this is the first time I had to deal with security descriptors, until now I always put them to NULL.